# Process something in each element of a matrix and return a value

Tags: ruby

I have matrix like this:

```
my_matrix = [['regular', '16/03/2009', '17/03/2009', '18/03/2009'],
             ['regular', '20/03/2009', '21/03/2009', '22/03/2009'],
             ['rewards', '26/03/2009', '27/03/2009', '28/03/2009']]
```

I need to verify if the first element is 'regular' or 'rewards' and, verify each date of the first element, process something and return a value.

For example:

```
['regular', '20/03/2009', '21/03/2009', '22/03/2009']
```

The first element is `'regular'` and, I need to loop through the rest of the array verifying if each date is a weekday or a weekend and then process something. If there are more weekends than weekdays process something , else, process another thing.

I've tried this:

```
HOTELS = {
  :RIDGEWOOD   => 'RidgeWood',
  :LAKEWOOD    => 'LakeWood',
  :BRIDGEWOOD  => 'BridgeWood'
}

def weekend?(date)
  datetime = DateTime.parse(date.to_s)
  datetime.saturday? || datetime.sunday?
end

def find_the_cheapest_hotel(text_file)

   @costumer_request = File.open(text_file){|io| io.each_line.map{|line| line.split(/[:,\s]+/)}}

   @costumer_request.each do |line|

     line.each do |value|
        if line.shift == 'regular' 
          if weekend?(line)
            print 'weekend regular'
          else
            print 'weekday regular'
          end

        elsif line.shift == 'rewards'
          if weekend?(line)
            print 'weekend rewards'
          else
            print 'weekday rewards'
          end
        end
end
```

It gets this `['regular', '16/03/2009', '17/03/2009', '18/03/2009']` and returns this 
weekday weekday weekday
I want to process something e each array not only in the first.

Comment: That sounds great! Go right ahead and do that. (Did you have a question? Did you try something and it didn't work? What?)

Comment: I put my source code in the question, please take a look :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still have not said what the problem is, and your code does not match your initial description very well. But I can certainly point to a place where things are going wrong at the outset:

```
    if line.shift == 'regular'
      # ...
    elsif line.shift == 'rewards'
      # ...
    end
```

Think about it. The initial `if` calls `shift`, and therefore *it does in fact shift the array*. The first element of the array is now gone forever. So suppose it was *not* `regular`. So now we get to the `elsif` condition. But I can tell you for a fact that this condition will *never* be true, because if the first element of the array was `rewards`, it is now lost; it has been removed from the array (the first element is now a date).

So, instead of shifting, just examine `line[0]` in both conditions. You can shift *later* when it's time to walk the rest of the array.

Comment: Here another question: After I verify the first element of the array. How can I verify the rest of the array ?

Comment: If it's another question, ask it as another question!